# next and prev button for different categories of images

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    divs.hide().first().show();
    $("button[name=next]").click(function (e) {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show next
    });
    $("button[name=prev]").click(function (e) {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // or .css('display','block');
        //console.log(divs.length, now);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

This is my first time developing a mobile apps and I am really slow in all this coding stuff.so my problem is, I have the above code to view previous and next image in my app.it works fine but when I have different categories of gallery need to be shown (eg: animals category,plants category,etc), and inside each categories, there are few images need to be displayed and can be controlled using the prev and next button (eg: animals [24 images], plants[20 images]), I encounter some problem.problem now is that the script only works on the first categories(eg:animals)..but when I want to view images in other categories (eg: plants), there seems to have problem with the counter. I need to click a few times the next button before the first images from the plant categories appear.

This is my related HTML and CSS for the above code:

HTML:

```
<body>

<!-- *************HOME PAGE**************** -->

<div data-role="page" id="home" data-title="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Menu Utama</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div><img id="Logo" src="images/logo.png"> </div> 

    <div data-role="content" class="content-primary">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

    <li><a href="#animal">
            <img src="images/animal-thumbnail.png" />
            <h3>category:animal</h3>
            <p>view animals </p>
            </a></li>

    <li><a href="#plant">
            <img src="images/plant-thumbnail.png" />
            <h3>category:plant</h3>
            <p>view plants</p>
            </a></li>

        </ul>

    </div> <!--/content-->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- *************CATEGORY ANIMAL PAGE**************** -->

<div data-role="page" id="animal" data-title="animal">

<div data-role="header">
.
.
.
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
<div class="mydivs">
    <div><img id="ContentPic" src="content-pic/animal1.png" alt="photo" /></div>
    <div><img id="ContentPic" src="content-pic/animal2.png" alt="photo" /></div>
    <div><img id="ContentPic" src="content-pic/animal3.png" alt="photo" /></div>

</div>

</div> <!--/content-->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
         <li><button name="prev" alt="Previous Tab"><img class="ContentPic" src="images/prev.png" /></button></li>
         <li><button name="next" alt="Next Tab"><img class="ContentPic" src="images/next.png" /></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- nav bar -->
        <h4></h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- *************CATEGORY PLANT PAGE**************** -->

<div data-role="page" id="plant" data-title="plant">
<div data-role="header">
.
.
.
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
<div class="mydivs">
    <div><img id="ContentPic" src="content-pic/plant1.png" alt="photo" /></div>
    <div><img id="ContentPic" src="content-pic/plant2.png" alt="photo" /></div>
    <div><img id="ContentPic" src="content-pic/plant3.png" alt="photo" /></div>

</div>


<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
         <li><button name="prev" alt="Previous Tab"><img class="ContentPic" src="images/prev.png" /></button></li>
         <li><button name="next" alt="Next Tab"><img class="ContentPic" src="images/next.png" /></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- nav bar -->
        <h4></h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- ************* END **************** -->
</body>
```

css

```
.mydivs {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.mydivs>div {
    width : 100%;
}
```

Comment: please share the relevant html sample also

Comment: whether the buttons are under `mydiv`

Comment: i have added the related code for it.tq for the response @ArunPJohny

Comment: whether each `mydivs` and the next/prev buttons are in different `content` elements or whether the set are always next to each other

Comment: i actually not quiet understand your question.so sorry.i am really messed up with all this code stuff

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wLXHS/1/

Comment: can you give a html sample with multiple categories

Comment: i update my html.basically right now i only make 2 categories to try.but i am supposed to do 8 categories of images.thank you again @ArunPJohny

Comment: @ArunPJohny it work!thank you so much for your help!and again i am really sorry for bothering you with this kind of problem.thanks again!

Comment: `.ready()` shouldn't be used in jQM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mydivs').children().hide().filter(':first-child').show().addClass('current');
    $("button[name=next]").click(function (e) {
        var $current = $(this).closest('[data-role="footer"]').prev().find('.current').removeClass('current').hide(), $next = $current.next();
        if(!$next.length){
            $next = $current.parent().children().first();
        }
        $next.show().addClass('current'); // show next
    });
    $("button[name=prev]").click(function (e) {
       var $current = $(this).closest('[data-role="footer"]').prev().find('.current').removeClass('current').hide(), $prev = $current.prev();
        if(!$prev.length){
            $prev = $current.parent().children().last();
        }
        $prev.show().addClass('current'); // show next
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wLXHS/)

Comment: i tried and it work!thanks a lot.you really have help me with this.sorry for troubling you with this.i'll manage myself to understand the code.thanks again!